# Custom rewrite rules for archive page and single post

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm building a Wordpress site with several custom post types. Every post type is a different magazine. I have also a custom meta fields for a magazine year and issue.

I would like to have urls (used archive.php):

```
http://my_site/magazine/name/
http://my_site/magazine_name/year/
http://my_site/magazine_name/year/issue/
```

I made it by code:

```
function magazine_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%issue_year%', '([0-9]{4})');
    add_rewrite_tag('%issue%', '([0-9])');
}
add_action('init', 'magazine_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

and:

```
function magazine_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^([a-z]+)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9])?', 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&issue_year=$matches[2]&issue=$matches[3]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^([a-z]+)/([0-9]{4})?', 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&issue_year=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'magazine_rewrite_rules');
```

Off course I have also a custom queries in archive.php. And it works fine.

But now, my urls for single articles doesn't work. By default, it is:

```
http://my_site/magazine/post-title
```

but it's show all articles from magazine like url (and it used archive.php template):

```
http://my_site/magazine/
```

How add properly rewrite rules for single custom posts? It is possible, I would like to have urls for single post (only for chosen custom post types) in this format:

```
http://my_site/magazine/year/issue/post-title
```

Comment: Multiple notes: (1) The 4th argument is the number of arguments a filter or action takes. And `10` is the default _priority_. You can leave both off in that case … or try a higher number. (2) Have you checked the resulting rewrite rules? Also make sure you check the order of those rules as they are processed in their order. Dump `$GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']`. (3) Have you added `query_vars`  that might conflict?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution! 
A Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzur plugin was very helpful: https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/

So now, I have such working urls...

**single.php:**

```
/magazine-name/issue-year/issue/article-name
```

**archive.php:**

```
/magazine-name/issue-year/issue
/magazine-name/issue-year
/magazine-name
```

On a custom post editor page in wp-admin I use Advanced Custom Fields plugin for issue year and issue. You can also define meta fields by yourself.

Next I added rewrite tags for issue year and issue:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%issue_year%', '([0-9]{4})' );
    add_rewrite_tag('%issue%', '([0-9]+)' );
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag');
```

Next, I added rewrite rewrite rules for any combination of urls:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    // URL: /magazine/year/issue/title
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9])/(.?.+?)?(:/([0-9]+))?/?$', 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&issue_year=$matches[2]&issue=$matches[3]&name=$matches[4]', 'top');

    // URL: /magazine/year/issue
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9])?$', 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&issue_year=$matches[2]&issue=$matches[3]', 'top');

    // URL: /magazine/year
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/([0-9]{4})?$', 'index.php?post_type=$matches[1]&issue_year=$matches[2]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
```

At the end I replace standard urls for my own, with issue year and issue

```
function custom_permalink($url, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type == 'magazine-name-1' || $post->post_type == 'magazine-name-2' || $post->post_type == 'magazine-name-2' ) {
        global $post;

        $post_type = $post->post_type;
        $issue_year = get_field('issue_year', $post->ID); // ACF; for meta: get_post_meta($post->ID, '$issue', true);
        $issue = get_field('issue', $post->ID); // ACF

        $url = str_replace( $post_type . '/', $post_type . '/' . $issue_year . '/' . $issue . '/' , $url);
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 2);
```